# PHP regex match capital html

Tags: php, regex

I am making a small linux driven PHP utility that fetch web pages and images from a Windows server. All is working well except filenames and references. Windows does not mind about capital letters or not but the linux client does.

Files served are containing links that sometimes are referenced with capital letters, sometimes not.

I am saving all files using capital letters, no problem there.

After getting the webpage using curl into a string, I wish to ensure that any links in the "web page string" - to other "internal" htmlpages is correct.

Files are referenced as "A1.HTML", "a23.hTmL", "A123.htm", "a2.html", "a213.HTML" and so on.

Common pattern is: The link will ALWAYS start with a (or A) followed by a counter (1 through 999) and the extension .html (or .htm or .HTM or .HTML)

Code:

```
function get_url(){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_SESSION['GETURL']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

// Now the page is stored in $output

// Replace a|A\d{1,999}\.[HTML|html|Html|htm|Htm|HTM] with A <NUMBER FROM BEFORE> <dot> HTML

// maybe use preg_replace
```

Example (problem page "A3.HTML"):

Before:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>MYTITLE</TITLE><META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' content='8;URL=A3.HTML'> ...........
```

or:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>MYTITLE</TITLE><META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' content='8;URL=A3.html'> ...........
```

or:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>MYTITLE</TITLE><META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' content='8;URL=a3.HTML'> ...........
```

or:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>MYTITLE</TITLE><META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' content='8;URL=A3.HTML'> ...........
```

Any help forming a suitable function to ensure the formatting in the string is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

/Niels

Comment: This isn't an OS thing, so much as it is a file system thing. Windows/OS X use case-insensitive formats by default, but Linux uses case-sensitive. Possible other approaches: Make a partition/disk image/ram disk with a case-insensitive file system and serve that folder. Make all file names lower case, and use something like mod_rewrite to lowercase the requested file path.

Comment: activating mod_speling in apache would solve the issue too.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
// Replace a|A\d{1,999}\.[HTML|html|Html|htm|Htm|HTM] with A <NUMBER FROM BEFORE> <dot> HTML
$content = preg_replace('/a(\d{1,3})\.html?/i','A$1.HTML',$output);
```

The preg_replace `/i` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) means that the regex is non-case sensitive. The `$1` in the replacement string is a [backreference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) - this means it will take the captured group from the matching string (in this case, the number) and apply it to the replacement.

Comment: Would it be `\\d` or `\d`?

Comment: @Tryth No need to esacpe that!! Check [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: @Enissay Oops! Was unaware. Have now edited the post to remove the unnecessary backslashes.